# Kubectl: fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

Tags: macos, go, kubernetes, gcloud

I haven't used kubectl in about two months.  It was working well in June but now I get the following error:

```
$ kubectl
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2cb65a5, 0x21)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95 fp=0x7fff5fbff810 sp=0x7fff5fbff7f0
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:108 +0xa0 fp=0x7fff5fbff840 sp=0x7fff5fbff810
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:486 +0xa1 fp=0x7fff5fbff880 sp=0x7fff5fbff840
runtime.rt0_go(0x7fff5fbff8b0, 0x1, 0x7fff5fbff8b0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x7fff5fbffa38, 0x0, 0x7fff5fbffa40, 0x7fff5fbffa5c, 0x7fff5fbffa6c, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:158 +0x183 fp=0x7fff5fbff888 sp=0x7fff5fbff880
```

I've read that this can be caused by websense but I don't have websense installed on my Mac.  The only thing that has changed to my knowledge was a routine update to Max OSX (10.12.6), and a routine update to gcloud (163).

I've tried reinstalling kubectl, gcloud, but it still fails.  As far as I can tell there is something wrong with Go, and I think Go is part of the core library included in gcloud sdk.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot/fix this?  I cannot connect to any of my pods due to this issue.

Comment: If you're installing the `kubectl` binary, there's nothing wrong with go, because you're not building anything. If you are building `kubectl` yourself, then have you updated to the latest Go installation? Also, websense isn't the only anti-malware tool that has been known to interfere with Go binaries.

Comment: Did not build myself.  Any way to properly troubleshoot this rather than take shots in the dark?  This is an enterprise controlled laptop so it's not easy to just disable security software.

Comment: You might be able to get around it yourself with the recommendation here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8801, though that will require familiarizing yourself with the k8s build system. There may be a way to whitelist the binary with your security software, but otherwise there's not really a programming related question here.

Comment: You seem certain this is related to security software, but that is an assumption and I'm not convinced.  Why do you think this is related to security software?

Comment: I suspect security software, because every instance of this issue coming up has been related to security software, except in the case of developers using dtrace on the process which you made no mention of. The only reason to have a `bsdthread_register` error is if `libSystem.dylib` was forced into the go process which would interfere with Go's own thread creation.

Comment: You're right, the cylance policy on my system was causing the problem.  After upgrading to a newer version of cylance the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error on mac os 12. Per this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1142), it was caused by old version `aws-iam-authenticator`. The issue is resolved after reinstalling the `aws-iam-authenticator` through

```
brew install aws-iam-authenticator
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a library change for system calls in MacOS 12. Older binaries use an old library which isn't supported anymore.

Update your kubectl to a new version. This should fix it.

If you can't update because you need an older version (e.g. because of api changes) you can build the needed kubectl using a new go version.

Necessary:

go 1.11 or newer

```
brew install go
```

Get repo

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git
```

Select version needed. e.g. 1.11.3

```
git checkout tags/v1.11.3
```

Build

```
GO111MODULE=off make
```

`GO111MODULE=off` turns off modules which are needed by default since go v1.16. If your kubernetes version is newer it might be necessary to have them turned on. If that is the case just leave out `GO111MODULE=off`.

When the build is done you can find the kubectl for your system in `_output/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because of OSX upgrade to 12. Re-linking minikube after upgrading it fixed the issue for me.

`$ brew link --overwrite minikube`